# How to filter array of objects by another array of objects and add key/value to the result array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two arrays, let's say

```
const array1 = [{ID: 1, msg: "xxx"},{ID: 2, msg: "eeee"},{ID: 3, msg: "ffff"},{ID: 4, msg: "yyy"}]
const array2 = [{intensity: 1, location: "AAAAA"},{intensity: 1, location: "WWWWW"},{intensity: 4, location: "RRRRR"}]
```

As you can notice, the `intensity` in `array2` isn't unique.

I managed to find objects in `array1` where `ID === intensity` but for a single object (doesn't filter duplicates) with this line :

```
const resultArray = array1.filter((elem) => array2.find(({ intensity }) => elem.ID === intensity));
```

The `resultArray` here is

```
resultArray = [{ID: 1, msg: "xxx"},{ID: 4, msg: "yyy"}]
```

But the desired output should be

```
resultArray = [{ID: 1, msg: "xxx"},{ID: 2, msg: "eeee"},{ID: 3, msg: "ffff"},{ID: 4, msg: "yyy"}]
```

And I would like to add `location` to `resultArray` where there is a match, so `resultArray` would be

```
resultArray = [{ID: 1, msg: "xxx", location: "AAAAA"},{ID: 1, msg: "xxx", location: "WWWWW"},{ID: 4, msg: "yyy",location: "RRRRR"}]
```

Comment: You have two desired outputs, which are different from each other. `find` returns the first object that causes the function specified to return true, so there's no reason for it to return the items with `ID: 2` or `ID: 3`...

Comment: The final desired output should be the last line in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a hash table for the messages and map the wanted properties.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ ID: 1, msg: "xxx" }, { ID: 2, msg: "eeee" }, { ID: 3, msg: "ffff" }, { ID: 4, msg: "yyy" }],
    array2 = [{ intensity: 1, location: "AAAAA" }, { intensity: 1, location: "WWWWW" }, { intensity: 4, location: "RRRRR" }],
    msgs = array1.reduce((m, o) => (m[o.ID] = o, m), {}),
    result = array2.map(({ intensity, location }) =>
        ({ ...msgs[intensity], location }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if this solution supports adding multiple variables other than `msg` ?

Comment: please see above by taking an object as value for the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

my way..

```js
const array1 = 
      [ { ID: 1, msg: "xxx"} 
      , { ID: 2, msg: "eeee"} 
      , { ID: 3, msg: "ffff"} 
      , { ID: 4, msg: "yyy"} 
      ] 
       
const array2 = 
      [ { intensity: 1, location: "AAAAA"} 
      , { intensity: 1, location: "WWWWW"} 
      , { intensity: 4, location: "RRRRR"} 
      ] 
 
const resultArray = array1.reduce((t,a1)=>
      {
      array2
        .filter(x=>a1.ID===x.intensity)
        .forEach (({ intensity, ...others})=>
          { t.push( {...a1, ...others} ) } )
      return t
      },[])

console.log ( resultArray )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is `others` ?

Comment: it's evry other data from each arr2 row

Comment: @Amine  this solution supports adding multiple variables other than msg and any  **other** variables from each array2 row

Comment: Thank you brother I really appreciate you solution, I used it for it's simplicity. Wish I can accept multiple answers

Answer (score 1):

Build an object for array1 elements, So that it will be useful for faster access while doing the array2 map.

```js
const array1 = [
  { ID: 1, msg: "xxx" },
  { ID: 2, msg: "eeee" },
  { ID: 3, msg: "ffff" },
  { ID: 4, msg: "yyy" },
];
const array2 = [
  { intensity: 1, location: "AAAAA" },
  { intensity: 1, location: "WWWWW" },
  { intensity: 4, location: "RRRRR" },
];

const all = {};
array1.forEach(({ ID, msg }) => (all[ID] = msg));

const res = array2.map(({ intensity, location }) => ({
  ID: intensity,
  msg: all[intensity],
  location,
}));

console.log(res)
```

Alternatively, use `find` on array1 to get the `msg` directly if your array1 data size is not big concern.

```js
const array1 = [
  { ID: 1, msg: "xxx" },
  { ID: 2, msg: "eeee" },
  { ID: 3, msg: "ffff" },
  { ID: 4, msg: "yyy" },
];
const array2 = [
  { intensity: 1, location: "AAAAA" },
  { intensity: 1, location: "WWWWW" },
  { intensity: 4, location: "RRRRR" },
];

const res = array2.map(({ intensity, location }) => ({
  ID: intensity,
  msg: array1.find(({ ID }) => ID === intensity)?.msg ?? '',
  location,
}));

console.log(res)
```